# multiple instances of a class, loading images, make more efficient in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am making a game that has 100 bees chase you and they have sprites. When they hit you, you lose a life. If you get hit by all 100, you die and the game resets. The problem is that when it resets, it reloads the images for each bee. This occurs 100 times and with 2 pictures each, it adds up and creates a severe delay.

This is my code to get the images:

```
public void loadPic(){//open up all of the images and store them in an ArrayList
    String beeDirectory="img/beeImgs/";
    File folder = new File(beeDirectory);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++){
        beeImgs.add(new ArrayList<BufferedImage>());
    }

    for(int h=0;h<listOfFiles.length;h++){
        File file=listOfFiles[h];
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            try{
                File folder2=new File(beeDirectory+file.getName()+"/");
                File[]listOfFiles2=folder2.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++){
                    File file2 = listOfFiles2[i];
                    if (file2.isFile() && file2.getName().endsWith(".png")){
                            beeImgs.get(h).add(ImageIO.read(new File(beeDirectory+file.getName()+"/"+file2.getName())));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear why there are 200 images. Do all the bees have different images? Or is it the same image for all?

Comment: @AndyTurner there are 2 images each. 100 bees, so it is like it's loading 200 images

Comment: Can't you just share the references to those two images amongst all the bees then?

Comment: Or alternatively use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern (pun unintentional)

Comment: @JBlaz thank you that is what i needed. If you post that as an answer, I will checkmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue to use the original objects. Create them one time then when they get to the user hide them and re-position them at the start instead of getting rid of them and recreating. There should be absolutely zero delay.